# Powerball number generator python

Tags: python

I am trying to make powerball generator from [openbook project](http://openbookproject.net/pybiblio/practice/wilson/powerball.php).

Here is my full code:

```
    import random

print "Official (but fruitless) Powerball number generator"

in1 = raw_input("How many sets of numbers?")

try:
    in1 = int(in1)
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid Input"
    exit()

a = range(1,53)

for x in xrange(in1):
    print " "
    print "your number:",
    for i in xrange(5):
            b = a[random.randint(0,len(a)-i)]
            a.remove(b)
            print b,

    print "Powerball:",
    for i in xrange(1):
            c= a[random.randint(0,len(a)-i)]
            a.remove(c)
            print c,
```

Problem with this code is, soon list indexes out of range.

I tried to find some of the code like [this](http://www.pro9ramming.com/-python-powerball-number-generator-t-1199.html). But it also have problem that it does not always print **unique** "your numbers" and it is also bit complex.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the task is defined, but don't you want to re-fill your lists after/before each draw?

Currently you're emptying it with `list.remove`, which actually removes an item from the list. After enough draws - the list will be empty.

```
for x in xrange(in1):
    a = range(1,53) # moved into loop
    print " "
    print "your number:",
    # .. same code from here on
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I was not re-filling it again. Thanks, I was trying to figure it out from about 2 hours

Comment: Happens to all of us :-) Try and use a debugger if possible.